# Cannot create primary key using already created index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, primary-key

I have a table `ideas` with columns `idea_id`, `element_id` and `element_value`.

Initially, I had created a composite primary key(`ideas_pkey`) using all three columns but I started facing size limit issues with the index associated with the primary key as the `element_value` column had a huge value.

Hence, I created another unique index hashing the column with possible large values

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ideas_pindex ON public.ideas USING btree (idea_id, element_id, md5(element_value))
```

Now I deleted the initial primary key `ideas_pkey` and wanted to recreate it using this newly created index like so

```
alter table ideas add constraint ideas_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("idea_id", "element_id", "element_value") USING INDEX ideas_pindex;
```

But this fails with the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ideas_pindex"
LINE 2: ...a_id", "element_id", "element_value") USING INDEX ideas_...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 209
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primary key index can't be a functional index. You can instead just have a unique index on your table, or create another column storing the md5() of your larger column and use it in the PK.

That being said, there is also another error in your query: If you want to specify an index name, you can't specify the PK columns (they are derived from the underlying index). And if you want to specify the pk columns, you can't specify the index name/definition, as it will be automatically created. See the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: Makes sense. However, I am not sure if having the md5 column as the primary key would help me use this composite primary key for a foreign key relationship in some other table. Wdyt?

Comment: maybe it would be easier to have a simple identity PK that you can refer to and to have other mechanism to ensure content uniqueness? Duplicating large columns in multiple tables sounds wrong